# Preventing Fixed Div from covering other Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

need some help.
My setup:

1. I have a fixed Div ("myFixedDiv") that remains in place when scrolling till 
   "myFixedDiv" reaches another div ("footer"). Then it moves with scrolling.
2. The Div "myFixedDiv" is placed next to a div ("text") using: display:inline-block.

Now for my problem:

When the window is horizontally made smaller, "myFixedDiv" is vertically placed after "textDiv" as intended. Only thing is, the upper-half of "myFixedDiv" visibly overlaps "textDiv", covering part of the text. I want "myFixedDiv" to be vertically placed after "textDiv" by pushing "footer" down to allow for this.

See an example here:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Eddy66/q9mn1yL0/15/)
You may need to give a little scroll to make "myFixedDiv visible again after making the window smaller.

```
$(document).scroll(function() { var $self = $("#myFixedDiv"); $self.css('margin-top', 0); var myFixedDivOffset = $self.offset().top + $self.outerHeight(true); if (myFixedDivOffset > ($("#footer").offset().top - 30)) { $self.css('margin-top', -(myFixedDivOffset - $("#footer").offset().top)); } else { $self.css('margin-top', '30px'); } });
```

Answer (score 3):

Change fixed position to relative position of the div when you resize the window and it should be good

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9mn1yL0/19/)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#myFixedDiv").css('position','relative');
});
```

You can also add a condition based on the width of the body to change the CSS of  the div to relative or fixed position.

Comment: Thank you! However, I was hoping that as soon as "myFixedDiv" leaves the inline position that at that moment something happens to solve the problem. Or that in the exciting code a value needs changing (or to be added) that prevents "myFixedDiv" from covering the "textDiv".

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var $self = $("#myFixedDiv");
  $self.css('margin-top', 0);
  var myFixedDivOffset = $self.offset().top + $self.outerHeight(true);
  if (myFixedDivOffset > ($("#footer").offset().top - 30)) {
    $self.css('margin-top', -(myFixedDivOffset - $("#footer").offset().top));
  } else {
    $self.css('margin-top', '30px');
  }
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 601) $("#text").css('padding-bottom', '70px'); {
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 1);
  }
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 600) $("#text").css('padding-bottom', '0'); {
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 1);
  }
});
```